# how do i make a 3 dimensional list as a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im trying to take a file in the format

```
   Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2023-02-21,150.199997,151.300003,148.410004,148.479996,147.691666,58867200
2023-02-22,148.869995,149.949997,147.160004,148.910004,148.119400,51011300
```

and make it into week blocks and after that sort the weekly blocks into blocks of 5 weeks

i am able to sort into weekly blocks of 5 days a week but not sure how to proceed

```
    import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')

# Convert the 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Set the 'Date' column as the DataFrame index
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Resample the DataFrame to group data by weeks starting from Monday and ending on Friday
# Custom frequency alias 'W-FRI' represents weekly frequency ending on Friday
weekly_groups = df.resample('W-FRI')

# Iterate through the weekly groups
for name, group in weekly_groups:
    print(name)
    print(group)
```